# Instalação Cordova

Tags: cordova-plugin

Estou tentando instalar um plugin no Cordova e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
λ cordova plugin add https://github.com/jlsuarezs/cordova-plugin-brightness.git
Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/jlsuarezs/cordova-plugin-brightness.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963228 Error output:
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\PC-01\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4628-4719c51b\git-cache-d8f4069b\e9e697ceb9546a62c11c3bf3b6bdb867fe907844
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "E:\\Programas\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Programas\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "https://github.com/jlsuarezs/cordova-plugin-brightness.git" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\PROJETOS\APPS\medley02\node_modules\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: O erro está aqui: Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Provavelmente o plugin mudou de nome. Verifique no git dele.